# How to enable Intel TSX in i7-7700 cpu?

Tags: linux, x86, intel, cpu-architecture, intel-tsx

I have this Intel i7-7700 CPU. `lscpu` shows it has Intel TSX feature.

```
flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi 
mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs 
bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx 
est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer 
aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single intel_pt ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp 
kaiser tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms 
invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp 
hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
```

However, I'm unable to use it. I was trying to run the test program from this repository https://github.com/blue9057/intel-tsx-sample. I check `IA32_ARCH_CAPABILITIES` with `sudo rdmsr 0x10AH`, and it returns `0xc04` which indicates bit 7 (`TSX_CTRL`) is 0. So there is no TSX support. I'm not an expert, I tried to change the MSR with `sudo wrmsr 0x10ah 0xC84` and I get the following error,

```
wrmsr: CPU 0 cannot set MSR 0x0000010a to 0x0000000000000c84
```

I also try to read `IA32_TSX_CTRL` with `sudo rdmsr 0x122H` and get the following error,

```
rdmsr: CPU 0 cannot read MSR 0x00000122
```

I disable `secure boot` from `BIOS`

`lscpu` shows the `microcode: 0xf0`. I believe Intel disable this TSX feature with microde update. I'm not sure if this update is automatic or not. But as far I can remember I did not update any.

Not if this is relevent or not `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-210/arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h` files shows

```
#define MSR_IA32_TSX_CTRL               0x00000122
#define TSX_CTRL_RTM_DISABLE          BIT(0)  /* Disable RTM feature */
#define TSX_CTRL_CPUID_CLEAR          BIT(1)  /* Disable TSX enumeration */
```

I also comment out `#define TSX_CTRL_RTM_DISABLE` and `#define TSX_CTRL_CPUID_CLEAR` but no luck.

I was wondering if there is any way I can enable this feature. I'm not sure If I provide enough information on this. Please let me know what other information will be helpful. I will add them. Or if you can point me in some directions that will be helpful.

OS version: Linux xxxx 4.4.0-210-generic x86_64

**UPDATE**

complete `lscpu`

```
xxx@xxx:~$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 158
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               900.000
CPU max MHz:           4200.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              7199.80
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic 
sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse 
sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art 
arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc 
aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 
ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe 
popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 
3dnowprefetch epb invpcid_single intel_pt ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp 
kaiser tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust 
bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap 
clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp 
hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d 
arch_capabilities
```

Kernel log shows,

```
$dmesg | grep "tsx=on"
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-210-generic root=UUID=b528525a-2daa-4537-964e-106314e6a7bd ro quiet splash nokaslr tsx_async_abort=off tsx=on vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-210-generic root=UUID=b528525a-2daa-4537-964e-106314e6a7bd ro quiet splash nokaslr tsx_async_abort=off tsx=on vt.handoff=7

$dmesg | grep "TAA"
[    0.063012] TAA: Mitigation: Clear CPU buffers
[    0.209727] TAA CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html for more details.
```

Instead of using the example from the mentioned git repo, I was trying to run the following program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   volatile int result=-1;
   unsigned status;
   
   while(result != 1){
      if ((status = _xbegin()) == _XBEGIN_STARTED) {
         result=1;
         _xend();
      }else{
         printf("rtmCheck: Transaction failed\n");
         printf("Trying again ...\n");
         sleep(5);
      }
   }

   printf("rtmCheck : Result is %d\n", result);
   return 0;
}
```

`Makefile`

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -mrtm

rtmCheck: rtmCheck.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o rtmCheck rtmCheck.o

clean: 
    rm -f *.o rtmCheck
```

output:

```
rtmCheck: Transaction failed
Trying again ...
rtmCheck: Transaction failed
Trying again ...
```

Comment: Most Linux distros load up to date microcode.  (It's not persistent across reboots; mobo BIOS/firmware updates often include updated microcode, but normally it's up to the OS to have the latest.)  Also, Linux disables parts of TSX on purpose on some CPUs, e.g. check your `dmesg` / kernel log for `TAA: Mitigation: TSX disabled`.  I've tried booting with `tsx=on tsx_async_abort=off` on my Arch Linux 6.0.11 kernel, but it doesn't actually enable TSX like https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/tsx_async_abort.html says it should

Comment: Related: [Has Hardware Lock Elision gone forever due to Spectre Mitigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61310108) - RTM should still be available, in theory if the OS doesn't choose to disable it.

Comment: @PeterCordes. I forgot to mention, I also tried booting with `tsx=on`, and yes, it did not work for me either

Comment: `$ dmesg | grep "TAA"
[    0.063725] TAA: Mitigation: Clear CPU buffers
[    0.210471] TAA CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/tsx_async_abort.html for more details.` Not sure if I understand this. So, `TSX is not disabled` in my system?

Comment: Should be available, yes, unless something later disabled it.  My Arch Linux kernel 6.0.12 says `Unknown kernel command line parameters "tsx=on", will be passed to user space.`   If you use `lscpu`, does it show something other than `Tsx async abort:      Mitigation; TSX disabled`?  And does `rtm` show in /proc/cpuinfo or lscpu output?  Oh, yeah, in your `lscpu` output in the question, you have `rtm`.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I update the body of the question. After booting with `tsx=on`, I'm not seeing any `Unknown kernel command line parameters ... `

Comment: Good, then it's working as intended.  Your kernel is much older than mine; maybe something broke or was removed between 4.4 and 6.0.

Comment: @PeterCordes, so, booting with `tsx_async_abort=off tsx=on` should disable the mitigation, therefore TSX should work correct? `sudo rdmsr 0x10AH` still returns `0xc04`. So there is still no TSX support?

Comment: I don't know what that MSR is supposed to do.  Have you tried actually using RTM, with `xbegin` / `xend` instructions, and seeing if you can complete a transaction instead of having it always abort?  There should be some example / demo code around on SO and other places.  If RTM is enabled, user-space can just use it without doing anything with MSRs.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I update the question with the simple code that I'm trying to run. I was checking MSR just to figure out if TSX is enabled or not.

Comment: Ok yeah, looks like RTM doesn't actually work on your system, despite those kernel messages.  What you found from the MSR is correct.  Perhaps `rtm` still showing in your `lscpu` just indicates that it won't fault.  But no, my Skylake system doesn't even show RTM in `lscpu`, but xbegin doesn't fault. It does always abort the transaction, though, like yours.  (So it's good that the kernel doesn't let the CPU advertize RTM, so applications don't waste time trying it when it's always going to abort.)

Comment: So according to `https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/tsx.c` enabling TSX is still possible for development.

Comment: When you post URLs in comments, leave them bare so they work as hyperlinks! (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/tsx.c)  Not in `code formatting`.  But yeah, the docs say it's supposed to be possible to enable it. I haven't dug into the details of which of those functions Linux actually calls when.